# Video Software Advice

Tags: export, edit-mode, video

I know this is not directly blender related, but I do not know where else to ask for me to get helpful answers.

I am working with blender and actually making a video for the first time. I am syncing it to a music file I have, and have rendered out each picture for every frame because I was originally advised to do it that way.

I need advice on what program I should use to put videos together in. My school is currently providing iMovie for me, but my future projects will not have access to this or any Apple computers. Whether the programs are free or not, I would simply find it helpful to get some recommendations on what video editors and techniques that others have found to be helpful. I have only a slight idea of what most people use, and I never know what version of a product to get. I have already tried using my version of Adobe Permier, but it just crashed a few times and then refused to cooperate with importing my media.

So, any general advice to help a new animator?

Comment: Blender has a video sequence editor. Does this not meet your needs for any specific reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Blender itself.

Comment: Ask on [Software recomandations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try out a wonderful piece of software that is free as in beer and used in extremely high end finishing, try [Davinci Resolve 14](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/ca/products/davinciresolve).

Answer (score 1):

Blender can also be used as a video editor (select Video Editing from the Choose Screen Layout dropdown near the top). It can be used to import video, sound, and even scenes before they are rendered. The video can then be exported by rendering the animation for scene 1 (best to use a video file for export).